# Do people use any tools to make Rich UI on Web Application?

Tags: user-interface, gui-design

As titled, take ASP.NET/Perl/PHP for example.

Because I don't have chance to work with UI Designer/or know anyone like that, so I really wonder do they use any tools to do the UI design?

I don't mean tools like PhotoShop or Flash to make the graphic, but I mean like writting CSS, Table layout/color, Div, JQuery animation etc.

I know for ASP.NET Visual Studio have some support on UI design, but is very minimum compares to like ExpressionBlend for WPF/Silverlight.

I have been still typing everything when I do the UI Design for ASP.NET.

So I wonder do people use any tools to help doing UI Design?  Or everyone take it like a man to type everything else like what we did back then with NotePad?

Comment: Aesthetic artists 'draw it' and you realize it by 'coding it' - no shortcuts :)

Comment: @Nupul now I understand why there is position for UI designer, is not only for phototype the GUI, but write so many GUI code for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is good. GUI implementation in HTML is insane. Take a look at [Artisteer](http://www.artisteer.com)
It may help a bit. Look at the video. The tool allows you to not only create a design from a template but also generates HTML and CSS code. I don't know if the demo version supports ASP.NET but I know that the production version now supports ASP.NET (please check before you buy)!

You could also consider using 3rd party GUI controls on top of VS. Some of those are much more pretty and provide functionality too.

The 'designer' spirit is usually required and not too many tools can replace that as you know.

Comment: +1 I see, so I could just get the template html and css and edit to fits my ASP.NET app too.  I will try look for one that's similar but open source.  But yes, I did use some 3rd party GUI control, just sometime their style is doesn't match one and the other.  So I could implement my own control.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups) for UI design.  The last site that I worked on I used Adobe Dreamweaver for implementation.  Most of the CSS that I have worked with has been coded by hand (and debugged using a plugin called [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to assist).

Comment: +1 ooo phototype tool!  I never thought about using that.  All I did was just do some quick sketches on paper lol

Comment: If you are in to prototypes, Silverlight's Blend offers a tool called sketchflow that could be of interest: http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/sketchflow_overview.aspx

Comment: @EmmadKareem o nice, thanks for telling me about that. I seen that before I didn't know it was a prototypes tools.  I guess is always good at least know about the tool.